# Cannot get out of wire mode (Viewport shading -> Solid / Max Draw Type -> Textured / Shading - Hidden Wire -> Unchecked)

Tags: wireframe

I have this blend file (version 2.79) which comprises several models with armature.

I'm trying to edit one of the models, but when I enter edit mode is only displayed in Wireframe even though;

- View Shading is set to Solid
- Shading-Hidden Wire Unchecked
- Max Draw Type is set to textured.

I can only see it in solid mode if I set the "Adjust edit cage to modifier result" in the Armature modifier, but then the 3d gizmo is displayed where the original mesh model is (at the origin) so I cannot edit it that way.

Is there any setting I'm missing so I can see the model in solid mode when editing and have the 3d gizmo in place?

Comment: Have you tried looking in Viewport overlays and see if this wireframe option option is the reason? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBFVb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBFVb.png) I apologise if this isn't it, I'm new here and I'm normally not very good at helping ha ha.

Comment: Hey, thanks for jumping in, really appreciated! I'm on 2.79, I guess the equivalent would be Mesh Display->Overlays? I have tried checking/unchecking everything but no avail :(

Comment: That's Unfortunate, I'm currently on the 3+ version